# Bootstrap 4 grids

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to make a layout on bootstrap4, and then I can not. Thank you in advance!

```
<div class="col-8">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Now it goes like this

[image: Now it goes like this]

And need to look like this

[image: And need to look like this]

Comment: You can try using float left or changing the display of the divs to inline-block.

Comment: What do you want the order if div’s to look like when the screen resizes?

Comment: No possible with BS4 with the current structure.

Comment: Can you change your html structure ?

Comment: @BinaryBuilder there is without screen resize (not col-md or col-sm, only col-8) viewport width=1024

Comment: @Programmer I try use float left and display inline block; result like in first image;

First col-4 height same col-8 height; not floating left

Comment: @Girish Because I'm first time in stackoverflow and showed error like write anything else (little information)

Comment: @DaurenSyzdykov, it's ok. someone will help you with your issue, but you must help yourself first. Try to solve it on your own and then share here what you have tried. Please read: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Using `float: left;` styling on the columns will give you this effect.

Below I changed the `<img>` tag to a `<div>` with a border to give the same visuals since I don't have `img.jpg`. If you swap those back in it should still work.

I added the styling to the `col` classes by just adding:

```
.col-4, .col-8{
    float:left;
}
```

Though, I would recommend adding a class to the outer div's with this styling instead of pigy-backing on bootstrap's classes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<style>
    .small-card {
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        border: solid 2px #333;
    }

    .large-card{
        height: 120px;
        width: 100%;
        border: solid 2px #333;
    }

    .col-4, .col-8{
        float:left;
    }
</style>
<div class="col-8">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="large-card"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="small-card"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="small-card"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="small-card"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="small-card"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="small-card"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="small-card"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="small-card"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="small-card"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="small-card"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```